# Pass a prop to CSS property in Astro

Tags: css, reactjs, astrojs

I am trying to create a Card component and set its background image url to the file in assets folder which I am getting through props. I am working in Astro.

index.astro:

```
---
const toursData = [
        { name: 'Tour1', path: '/tour1', img: 'src/assets/img/tour1.jpg' },
        { name: 'Tour2', path: '/tour2', im: 'src/assets/img/tour2.jpg' },
        { name: 'Tour3', path: '/tour3', img: 'src/assets/img/tour3.jpg' },
    ]
---

<div>
   {toursData.map(i => <Card name={i.name} path={i.path} img={i.img} />)}
</div>
```

Card.astro:

```
---
const { name, path, img } = Astro.props
---

<li class="card"><a href={path}>{name}</a></li>

<style>
    .card {
        background-image: url(???);
    }
</style>
```

How do I pass img prop to the background-image property so that each Card component has its own background image?

Would this be the best approach or is there a better way?

```
<li class="card" style={`background-image: url(${img});`}><a href={path}>{name}</a></li>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things needed for this to work.

1. Because your images are in the `src/` directory (rather than in `public/`), you need to import them in `index.astro` rather than referring to them with strings. This will import an image metadata object with a `src` property you can pass to your cards.

   ```
   ---
   import img1 from '/src/assets/img/tour1.jpg';
   import img2 from '/src/assets/img/tour2.jpg';
   import img3 from '/src/assets/img/tour3.jpg';


   const toursData = [
     { name: 'Tour1', path: '/tour1', img: img1 },
     { name: 'Tour2', path: '/tour2', img: img2 },
     { name: 'Tour3', path: '/tour3', img: img3 },
   ]
   ---

   <div>
     {toursData.map(i => (
       <Card
         name={i.name}
         path={i.path}
         img={i.img.src}
       />
     ))}
   </div>
   ```
2. In your card component, use [`define:vars`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#definevars) to pass the image source as a variable to your CSS styles. But with one caveat: CSS does not permit CSS variables (aka custom properties) inside `url()`, so we do that as part of `define:vars`:

   ```
   ---
   const { name, path, img } = Astro.props
   ---

   <li class="card"><a href={path}>{name}</a></li>

   <style
     define:vars={{ image: `url("${img}")` }}
   >
     .card {
       background-image: var(--image);
     }
   </style>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works great. It even eliminates my other problem which was that there were no images showing up after running npm run build and accessing the website on other device.

Comment: Also, is it better to store images like this in a /public folder? I know that [Astro recommends](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#where-to-store-images) keeping them in /src so that they can be optimized afterwards.

Comment: Depends a bit. `/public` works if you just want to refer to the images with a static string pathname and don’t need to modify them at all. Importing images from `/src` makes it possible to optimise them using Astro’s `<Image>` and `<Picture>` components. It also ensures a unique, hashed URL that can be aggressively cached, and ensures images exist when you import them, so has some nice advantages.